# Haskell websockets header

Tags: haskell, web, websocket, http-headers, monads

I am trying to read websockets header in haskell.

Current code is as follows

```
import Network
import Network.Socket.Internal
import Text.Printf
import Control.Monad
import Control.Monad.IO.Class
import Data.Maybe
import Data.List
import Data.Digest.Pure.SHA (bytestringDigest, sha1)
import Text.Regex
import System.IO

port :: Int
port = 8080

bufferLength :: Int
bufferLength = 2048

keyRegex :: String
keyRegex = "Sec-WebSocket-Key: (.+)(\r)"

response :: String
response = "HTTP/1.1 101 Web Socket Protocol Handshake\r\nUpgrade:     WebSocket\r\nConnection: Upgrade\r\nsec-websocket-accept:     changethis\r\n\r\n"

guidString :: String
guidString = "258EAFA5-E914-47DA-95CA-C5AB0DC85B11"

talk :: MonadIO m => Handle -> m String
talk handle = do liftIO $ hGetContents handle

main :: IO()
main = withSocketsDo $ do
  sock <- listenOn (PortNumber (fromIntegral port))
  printf "Listening on port %d\n" port
  forever $ do
    (handle, host, port) <- accept sock
    printf "Accepted connection from %s: %s\n" host (show port)
    hSetBuffering handle NoBuffering
    putStrLn $ talk handle
```

The code throws error

```
Main.hs:38:16:
    Couldn't match type `[Char]' with `Char'
    Expected type: String
      Actual type: [String]
    In the return type of a call of `talk'
    In the second argument of `($)', namely `talk handle'
    In a stmt of a 'do' block: putStrLn $ talk handle
```

How to print header string? Talk function should get the header string and return it to be printed.

Comment: Did you mean `talk handle >>= putStrLn`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Return type of `talk handle` is `(MonadIO m => m String)`.

`putStrLn` has type `String -> IO ()` or `[Char] -> IO ()`.

`[]` is a monad.

`putStrLn` expects a list of chars, but it gets a value of `(MonadIO m => m String)`.

`m` becomes a list, and `putStrLn` gets a value of type `[String]` and this is error.

---

As @Zeta suggests, use `talk handle >>= putStrLn` instead:

`>>=` is operator which allows to continue computation with the result from another computation. In your case, you can read `talk handle >>= putStrLn` as follows:

```
talk handle -- first compute it
  >>= putStrLn -- then take string from result of `talk handle` and print it
```

There won't be any error such was with `putStrLn $ talk handle`:

```
(>>=)                        :: Monad m => m a -> (a -> m b) -> m b
talk handle                  :: MonadIO m => m String
(>>=) (talk handle)          :: MonadIO m => (String -> m b) -> m b  
putStrLn                     :: String -> IO ()
(>>=) (talk handle) putStrLn :: IO () -- `m` becomes `IO`
```

---

#### Edited:

Here you can find introduction to `IO` monad: [LYHFGG, Input and Output](http://learnyouahaskell.com/input-and-output)

Here you can find introduction to monads in general: [LYHFGG, A Fistful of Monads](http://learnyouahaskell.com/a-fistful-of-monads#getting-our-feet-wet-with-maybe).

You should know about `Functor` and `Applicative` in order to read `A Fistful of Monads`. You can find it in book's contents anyway.

Comment: thanks. how would i go about storing talk result in string variable?

Comment: or to pass it to function with type String -> String?

Comment: @haskellstuff There are no variables in Haskell. You can bound `talk`'s result to a name like you did with `sock` and then use it like string constant. Or you can pass it to a function with type `String -> String` and then access it there. But, to do this, first you need either to bound `talk`'s result to a name and then pass it via argument to function or to use bound operator directly like `talk handle >>= \ s -> ... let r = f s ...`. Here, `s` is `talk handle`'s result and `f` is that function with type `String -> String`.

Comment: @haskellstuff you can't just access result of `talk` because it is inside of `IO` monad. I edited question to refer to good resources about monads.